# How can I create a log axis on a chart in Visual Basic to produce a mono-log chart

Tags: .net, charts, mschart

I am currently using a Microsoft Visual Studio.

And I created a line chart with my data. However, these data not vary linearly. As you can see in the picture below I want a log scale y axis and a linear scale x axis.

How do I modify the y axis to reflect this

[image]

Comment: whats a monolog chart exactly?

Comment: A monolog chart is like a normal graph.However,  my data range from a linear form on the x-axis (0,1,2,3...) and on the y-axis differently (0,1,10,100,1300) - take a look on this link: http://ecalculo.if.usp.br/funcoes/grandezas/exemplos/img_exemp/img-exemp/grafico3.gif

Comment: monolog means one log axis and one linear axis??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if thats a logarithmic y axis then try making the y axis scale logarithmic. Once your chart is created try

```
  Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IsLogarithmic = True
```

or in the form creator

[image]

and this will give you

[image]